# Android esim Activation Using EuiccManager

Tags: euiccmanager

I need to have a complete stable code or review for the below code to handle esim activation on Android platform, I used the code and adjusted it, which `was` shared from Google Docs, but again no result, Can someone pass by the same issue, and tell me what is wrong with the below code,
Issue is: calling the subscription function to download the esim profile, using the activation code, always Operation code and Error code returned as null, and I don't know where is the error.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
String results = "Init";
String googleTestActivationCode = "1$prod.smdp-plus.rsp.goog$3TD6-8L82-HUE1-LVN6";
String realeSimActivationCode = "LPA:1$consumer.rsp.world$I5JCY6O2BQT5NTAE";
String activationCode = realeSimActivationCode;
TextView txtViewResult ;
Button btn_activate ;
EuiccManager euiccManager ;
private static final String TAG = "EsimInstallationReceiver";
private static final String LPA_INSTALL_ACTION = "com.android.lpa.action.PROVISION";
```

```
//Register Receiver for Callback,
static final String ACTION_DOWNLOAD_SUBSCRIPTION = "download_subscription";
static final String LPA_DECLARED_PERMISSION = "com.plixera.esim.lpa.permission.BROADCAST";
BroadcastReceiver receiver ;

private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
private BroadcastReceiver downloadProgressReceiver;
private static final String ACTION_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS = "com.example.esim.DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS";
private Button btn_activate_lpa;
private EditText et_activation_code;
private static final int ACTIVATE_ESIM_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
```

```
//Register Receiver for Callback,
static final String ACTION_DOWNLOAD_SUBSCRIPTION = "download_subscription";
static final String LPA_DECLARED_PERMISSION = "com.plixera.esim.lpa.permission.BROADCAST";
BroadcastReceiver receiver ;

private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
private BroadcastReceiver downloadProgressReceiver;
private static final String ACTION_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS = "com.example.esim.DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS";
private Button btn_activate_lpa;
private EditText et_activation_code;
private static final int ACTIVATE_ESIM_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
```

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        findViews();
        startActivationProcess();

    }

}
```

```
private void findViews(){
    txtViewResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
    btn_activate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_activate);
    btn_activate_lpa = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_activate_lpa);
    et_activation_code = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_activation_code);
}

public void startActivationProcess(){
        btn_activate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(!et_activation_code.getText().toString().equals(""))
                    activationCode = et_activation_code.getText().toString().trim();
                Log.d(TAG,"Activation Code:"+activationCode);
                initiateEsimInstallation();
            }
        });
    }

  private void initiateEsimInstallation() {
        checkESimAvailability(this);
        getEuiCCInfo();
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(LPA_INSTALL_ACTION);
        intent.putExtra("activationCode", activationCode);
        //sendBroadcast(intent);
        //activateESim();
        registerReceiver();
    }

   public void registerReceiver(){
        BroadcastReceiver receiver =
                new BroadcastReceiver() {
                    @Override
                    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                        Log.d(TAG,"onReceive");
                        if (!LPA_INSTALL_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                            return;
                        }
                        int resultCode = getResultCode();
                        Log.d(TAG,"resultCode:"+resultCode);
                        int operationCode = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_EMBEDDED_SUBSCRIPTION_OPERATION_CODE,-1);
                        int errorCode = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_EMBEDDED_SUBSCRIPTION_ERROR_CODE,-1);
                        String smdxSubjectCode = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_EMBEDDED_SUBSCRIPTION_SMDX_SUBJECT_CODE);
                        String smdxReasonCode = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_EMBEDDED_SUBSCRIPTION_SMDX_REASON_CODE);




                        if (operationCode == OPERATION_DOWNLOAD && errorCode == ERROR_CARRIER_LOCKED) {
                            // handle specific error i.e tries to download but the device is carrier locked
                            Log.d(TAG,"Final Result:"+"to download but the device is carrier locked");
                        } else if (operationCode == OPERATION_SMDX) {
                            // handle all SM-DP+/SM-DS errors
                            Log.d(TAG,"Final Result:"+"handle all SM-DP+/SM-DS errors");
                        } else if (errorCode == ERROR_TIME_OUT) {
                            // handle all types of time out issues, regardless of operation.
                            Log.d(TAG,"Final Result:"+"regardless of operation.");
                        } else if ("8.1".equals(smdxSubjectCode) && "3.1".equals(smdxReasonCode)) {
                            // handle specific subject code and reason code: 8.1 and 4.1 means insufficient memory.
                            Log.d(TAG,"Final Result:"+"8.1 and 4.1 means insufficient memory.");
                        }
                        else   if (errorCode == ERROR_INVALID_ACTIVATION_CODE) {
                            // handle specific subject code and reason code: 8.1 and 4.1 means insufficient memory.
                            Log.d(TAG,"Final Result:"+"ERROR_INVALID_ACTIVATION_CODE");
                        }
                        else   if (errorCode == EMBEDDED_SUBSCRIPTION_RESULT_ERROR) {
                            // handle specific subject code and reason code: 8.1 and 4.1 means insufficient memory.
                            Log.d(TAG,"Final Result:"+"ERROR_INVALID_ACTIVATION_CODE");
                        }
                        Log.d(TAG,"Operation Code:"+operationCode);
                        Log.d(TAG,"Error Code:"+errorCode);

                        Intent resultIntent = intent;
                    }
                };
        this.registerReceiver(
                receiver,
                new IntentFilter(LPA_INSTALL_ACTION), null, null /* handler */);
        Log.d(TAG,"registerReceiver");
        // Download subscription asynchronously.
        DownloadableSubscription sub =
                DownloadableSubscription.forActivationCode(activationCode );
        Log.d(TAG,"forActivationCode");

        Intent intent = new Intent(LPA_INSTALL_ACTION);

        PendingIntent callbackIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                this, Activity.RESULT_OK, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);

        euiccManager.downloadSubscription(sub, true , callbackIntent);
        String activationCode = sub.getConfirmationCode();
        Log.d(TAG,"downloadSubscription:"+activationCode);

    }

    public void checkESimAvailability(Context context){
        euiccManager = (EuiccManager)context.getSystemService(Context.EUICC_SERVICE);
        boolean isEnabled = euiccManager.isEnabled();
        if (!isEnabled) {
            return;       //always isEnabled is false
        }
        results = results.concat("\nDevice Support eSIM:"+isEnabled);
        txtViewResult.setText(results);
    }

    public void getEuiCCInfo(){
        EuiccInfo info = euiccManager.getEuiccInfo();
        String osVer = info.getOsVersion();
        results =  results.concat("\n"+osVer);
        txtViewResult.setText(results);
    }
```

Comment: Why do you use "LPA_INSTALL_ACTION" when you download and install eSIM, as I know it should be "ACTION_DOWNLOAD_SUBSCRIPTION"